# Prompt value in the input text field

Tags: javascript

Heya stackoverflowers,

I've got a simple newbie question..

I'm working right now for a project, for a school where children can learn mathematics(tables)..
My problem is:

When the input field is not filled in and the user is filling anything in in the table for the questions, a prompt box appears with: Vul je naam goed in!(Which means fill your name correctly!)

So When they fill it in, in the prompt, I can store the value of it, but I can't maintain it to appear it in the text box..

Here's my code:

The HTML5:

```
<label id="naamask">Wat is je naam?                </label>
        <input type="text" id="naams" ng-model='naams' onchange='naamCheck();'><br/>
```

The Javascript I am using for onchange and other functions:

```
function naamCheck(){
  if(naam == null || naam == "" || naam == " "){
    naam = prompt("Vul je naam hier goed in!");
  }

}
```

and the naam variable is a global variable which I stored like this:

```
// GLOBALE VARIABELEN

  var naam = document.getElementById('naams').value;
```

I'd like to get some help with this newbie question:-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't maintain it to appear it in the text box"?

Comment: I can't get the value that is filled in in the prompt, to appear in the text box.. Just the value of the prompt as text in the text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code:

1. Gets the value from an input
2. Puts that value into a variable
3. Gets a new value
4. Puts that value into the same variable (overwriting the old value)

You haven't (and can't) created a reference to the `value` property of the input.

You have to assign the new value to the value property of the input:

```
document.getElementById('naams').value = new_value
```

Comment: So, how can I let that code work to appear the value in the text box? I'm new to Javascript so sorry for the easy question :)

Comment: @TaykTaykCFKayahan — You do what I said to do in this answer.

Comment: So I write this down at the code of my prompt, or the var naam variable?

Comment: @Quentin-- It didn't work properly.. It's prompting everytime I am filling anything in,,

Comment: @TaykTaykCFKayahan — That's a different problem, with a similar cause. You haven't updated the variable (that you're comparing to `null` and empty strings) with the new value of the input.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that :-)?

Comment: The same way that you set the value in the first place.

Comment: I'm kinda outa clues.. I really don't know how to do that:(

Comment: There are only 6 lines of code in the question. One of them does what you want.